# typescript inferred never is not never?

Tags: typescript

statement 1

```
type c = never extends never ? true : false // true
```

yup, as expected

statement 2

```
type d = never extends infer P ? P : false // never
```

P is `never` as expected

statement 3

```
type g = (never extends infer P ? P : false) extends never ? true : false // true
```

this makes sense, because we know from statement 2 P is `never` and from statement 1, `never` extends `never` is true, so it returns `true`

statement 4

```
type f = never extends infer P ? (P extends never ? true : false) : false // never, expecting true or at least false
```

this is totally unexpected, not only it did not returns `true`, it also did not returns `false`, but it returns `never` which is not in the options

this is very confusing, **WHY?**

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAxlC8UB2EBuEBOUIA9gSQBMBnZNTKAfimAwFdoAuKAMwEMAbY6Aeh5voQAUENCQohBGXRZc%20IqQCWSFhQAKVKBubsuvfihkix0AOZSAFIYpyCJKMtVYN1ba07cAlNjx3S1rGpaBigdD30BBmNwaBYpAJ95e0d1TQsNWwVpCiDBUPc9bzC9KD5sjAAaH0gYYGVzYOgAeyw2YCgOCDZidt1uIA)

Comment: Ref: [conditional types in release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional types [distribute over unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Distribution is the process by which a conditional type is applied to each union constituent and the result of each application is unioned. Distribution happens only if the condition is applied over a naked type parameter.

```
// Is is distributive because we have `T extends` the condition is over just the type parameter 
type Is<T> = T extends string ? "yes" : "no"

// Is is distributive we basically apply is to each constituent of string | number 
type T0 = Is<string | number> // =Is<string> | Is<number> = "yes" | "no"

// No distribution
type T1 = string | number extends string ? "yes" : "no" // "no"
```

`never` can be seen as the empty union, the union with no types. So when distributing over `never` we actually don't apply the conditional type ever, resulting in `never` regardless of the conditional type itself

```
// never => Is is never applied
type T2 = Is<never> // Distribute over nothing = never
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkGdQS2gTOAXATjARgVyTAbgU1HXwGMBDTSQgd0IAsyDQADAFVHwA8l8A7eSM1BI6hEgHt+MHJNjRxBFKABWlJMNHCAngAdCOsijIBbfDyUAoJLsJQAPKwB8oALyh2XHv2iRUMXgDmoAD8oABEWviQYaAAXOG84mEWFiAQ0HCgiL5oWDhMtERkkDDkADZlWqBkOjqVcsLiHGQkdKASvL7SmHzq4gBmoDn+QQA+oLyYxsSW1nruAAyu6XbDgaDjk9P4KM5pLvZrAc7j9lszzm4RUTHjYYnJqWAAck3ZfnkwklY27gCMyyOGwmUxmHG4fAEQz861C12icQSSVAaXuSRSTwm+EUrmcUAavGxO2qtTKMHw8B+81YACZlmcibsUWAACLIXLYQgKYmJEQjZaExRAA)

If your case you introduce a new type parameter `P` (with `infer P`) and then create a distributive type (`P extends never ? true : false`) over it. If `P` is `never` that conditional type is never applied, since you are distributing over the empty union and you get `never`

Comment: I'm confused. `type dd = never extends infer P ? true : false` is true, so `never extends infer P` can result in the conditional type being applied?  Why isn't it in the @tylim's case?

Comment: @RichN distribution only applies if we have a type parameter when we test `never` directly the behavior is different, the conditional type is applied.