# Typescript never vs [never]

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Why this doesn't work:

```
type IsNever<T> = T extends never ? true : false;

type A = IsNever<never>; // ->'never', but should be true
```

but this works:

```
type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false;

type A = IsNever<never>; // true
```

How square brackets [] help with type definition in this case?

Comment: never is an empty union. So there is union distribution in the conditional statement. By creating a tuple with never as its only element, typescript is forced to check the condition. Because [never] is a not empty union. it's well better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71193522/typescript-inferred-never-is-not-never)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't extends from type never. Correct type:

```js
type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false
```

Comment: type A = never extends never ? true : false
type B = never extends unknown ? true : false
This both types will result in true.